# Why does IE8 add an extra element?

Tags: html, css, debugging, internet-explorer

I know, nobody likes to debug IE. If you check out [this](http://entrec.elearningstudents.ca/) link below in IE8 or IE9(without compatibility view) it seems to be adding empty UL elements in the footer.

Comment: [Validate your HTML.](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fentrec.elearningstudents.ca%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) It should be always be your first step with problems like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have a few [validation errors](http://validator.w3.org/) on the page, including:

```
 <h5>Heavy Haul Platform Trailers</h2>
```

This could be causing the issue you’re seeing in IE 8.

Comment: and including missing </a> tags... <li ><p><a href="about/our-history.html" title="Our History" >Our History</p></li>

Comment: Aha, that one looks like it could have caused the extra `<ul>` issue.

Comment: ahhh, I think tinyMCE muse be parsing some of them out for some reason.